# Server segregation of nodejs and mongo in amazon

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Why there are single web service just for mongodb? Unlike LAMP, I will just install everything on my ec2. So now I'm deploying MEAN stack, should I seperate mongodb and my node server? I'm confused. I don't see any limitation mixing node with mongod under one single instance, I can use tools like mongolab as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it depends how much load you expect your application to have and whether or not you care about redundancy.

With mongo and node you can install everything on one instance. When you start scaling the first separation is to separate the application from the database. Often its easier to set everything up that way especially if you know you will have the load to require it.